# How to execute docker virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart?

Tags: docker, dbpedia, virtuoso

I want to use virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart.

I execute the following as defined in [virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart](https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart)

```
git clone https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart.git
cd virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart
COLLECTION_URI=https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/collections/latest-core VIRTUOSO_ADMIN_PASSWD=YourSecretPassword docker-compose up
```

First I want to ask what it must be the `VIRTUOSO_ADMIN_PASSWD=YourSecretPassword`. I mean where I can create such a password. Then, the third command `COLLECTION...` generates:

> `'COLLECTION_URI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Noting that I am on Windows.

If I execute the above commands in `git bash`, I get for the last command the following:

```
unexpected character "." in variable name near ".env"
```

Comment: `git bash` is just a port of bash to Windows provided *with* Git so that Git (which invokes bash here) can run. It's not part *of* Git. The actual problem is likely a special character in your password that bash is interpreting as a request to do something; if that's the case, you must protect that character from bash, usually using quotes (single or double) and/or backslashes. The `V1=val1 V2=val2 command` syntax is shorthand for `export V1=val1; export V2=val2; command` except that the variables are un-set (or restored) immediately after the command is run.

Comment: (How you would translate this to cmd.exe or other non-POSIX-shell CLIs depends on the non-POSIX-shell CLI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart` [README](https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart/blob/master/README.md) appears to answer your question about setting the Virtuoso Admin Password within that project.

Further project-specific questions about the `virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart` (such as how best to use it on Windows, which does not appear to have been documented yet) would probably be best [raised directly on that project](https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart/issues).